# Angular - Dynamic CSS Class in iteration

Tags: angular

In below code I want to give each answer option a different css class. Css Class should be mapped to answer `1,2,3,4` as `knock1,knock2,who-s,there`.

#### Template

```
    <label *ngFor="let answer of answers">
      <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="selectedOption" [value]="answer.value">
        {{answer.text}}
    </label>
```

#### Typescript

```
this.answers = [
  new Answer(value: 4, text: "Race"),
  new Answer(value: 3, text: "Con"),
  new Answer(value: 2, text: "dit"),
  new Answer(value: 1, text: "ion")
];
```

I'm a bit rusty in Angular, so I was hoping for a hint in the right direction.

I'm currently trying out, but to no succes, in the input-tag code:

```
[ngClass]="{'knock1': answer.value === 1}"
```

Comment: The simplest way would be to add an `inputClass` property to the `Answer` class, and to use `[ngClass]="answer.inputClass"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend naming your CSS classes according to your values and using string interpolation to render the correct class. This will keep your HTML relatively clean and flexible.

**app.component.css**

```css
.answer-color-1 {
  background-color: #7CAE7A;
}

.answer-color-2 {
  background-color: #839073;
}

.answer-color-3 {
  background-color: #6E6362;
}

.answer-color-4 {
  background-color: #4E4A59;
}
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<label class="radio-inline" *ngFor="let answer of answers">
  <span class="answer-color-{{answer.value}}">
    <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="selectedOption" name="inlineRadioOptions" [value]="answer.value" >
      {{answer.text}}
  </span>
</label>
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-53027265-conditional-css)**

Also try not to use the same id for multiple elements in a *ngFor loop.

Comment: I'm giving you the answer for your great effort on best-practice, pointing out potential bugs and the demo page.

Answer (score 1):

You are close except that you cannot style an input radio element, one option is to style the label element instead as follow:

```
<label class="radio-inline" *ngFor="let answer of answers"
     [ngClass]="{'knock1': answer.value === 1, , 'knock2': answer.value === 2}">
      <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="selectedOption" name="inlineRadioOptions" 
             id="inlineRadio1" [value]="answer.value">
        {{answer.text}}
</label>
```

Input radio elements (the round shape) cannot be noramlly styled as other HTML elements like div, etc.. but if you really want, there are work arounds, i can provide you if you really need.

Comment: Will the class be set on the input nonetheless? I need it for selenium, not to actually style the input.

Comment: Yes it will be applied nonetheless. Although I would question the practise of applying classes or ids for the sole purpose of testing. Have you considered [Protractor](https://protractor.angular.io/)?

Comment: Interesting Point. Protractor is another wrapper around selenium and we decided to directly use webdriver with python. Would you in general recommend protractor over python for Angular apps? Our e2e tests need to run against our mobile app and web apps in a specific manner. We are applying testing-specific classes since so called managers are dancing in circles like apes on cheap russian ethanol thinking Agile means us changing 95% of codebase on a weekly basis. This way we insure our testing classes won't disappear and "management" can shred another dozen of millions of greenback next year.

Comment: As @GordonWesterman said the class will be applied nonetheless, I did not know your real intention / use case. For testing either Protractor or directly selenium then I would recommned adding custom attributes e.g. sele-test on elements.

Comment: Interesting, do you have a code example or link of such custom attribute for the purpose of e2e-testing?

Comment: I think he is referring to simply using a custom attribute which naming convention clearly states its purpose. This also keeps you and others from confusing an identifier used for testing for styling information. Here is [a short article](https://blog.kentcdodds.com/making-your-ui-tests-resilient-to-change-d37a6ee37269?gi=1db216d3bffc) which further explains the idea.

Comment: Yes what I mean it is up to you to come up with a name make sense for you, the article @GordonWesterman have code samples. One important point I would like to add, is to prefix your custom attribute name with `data-` e.g. `data-your-custom-test` for best practice and avoid potential issues, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes and https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp