# Add how to add class name dynamically when array of object is iterated using ngfor

Tags: angular

I get the object like

```
{ name: 'filename', order: '', open: true, isEditOn: false, tempVal: '', id: 0}
```

when I iterate an array of objects... Now I want to add the class of the div like

```
obj.filename + obj.id
```

I have tried like `[ngClass] = "{obj.filename + obj.id}"`..

Comment: Could you please add whatever code you have tried?

Comment: You need use [className]="obj.filename+obj.id", [ngClass] is for asing class if a condition is satisf, e.g. `[ngClass]="{'classname':condition}"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular - Dynamic CSS Class in iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53027265/angular-dynamic-css-class-in-iteration)

Comment: according to the data provided you have a property called `name` but you are trying to access a undefined property called `filename`

Answer (score 2):

Try like below,

Considering your object has name (i.e you mentioned it as filename but object has name property) and id properties. We can generate class like below

```
<div *ngFor="let item of arrayItems" [className]="item.name + item.id">
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: I am using 
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1202.14
@angular-devkit/build-angular   12.2.14
@angular-devkit/core            12.2.14
@angular-devkit/schematics      12.2.14
@angular/cdk                    12.2.13
@angular/cli                    12.2.14
@schematics/angular             12.2.14
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.3.5

and it works!  Can you verify it works and mark it as an answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use String Interpolation:

```
class="{{obj.filename + obj.id}}"
```

Answer (score -1):

What about this ?

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of items" [class]="item.name + item.id"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Change what you tried

```
[ngClass] = "{obj.name + obj.id}"
```

to this one

```
[ngClass] = "obj.name + obj.id"
```

I assumed `obj.filename` is typo of `obj.name`.